# Find the splitting field of $f=x^4+x^3+2x^2+x+1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the splitting field of $f=x^4+x^3+2x^2+x+1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

So according to wolfram alpha, the roots of this polynomial ate $\pm i$, $-\sqrt[3]{-1}$, and $(-1)^{2/3}$.

So just knowing that can't I say that the splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[3]{-1})$?

Comment: $f(x) =  (x^2+1)(1+x+x^2)$, clearly the splitting field of $1+x+x^2$ is $\mathbb{Q}(e^{2i \pi / 3})$, and the splitting field of $x^2+1$ is $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, but $e^{2i \pi / 3} = -1/2 + i\sqrt{3}/2$ and $\sqrt{3}$ isn't in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, hence the splitting field of $f(x)$ is $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{3})$ whose degree is... ?

Comment: The degree should be four I believe

Comment: I guess we can write that $K = \mathbb{Q}(i) \simeq \mathbb{Q}[x] / (x^2+1)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{3}) = K(\sqrt{3}) \simeq K[x] / (x^2-3)$ since $x^2-3$ stays irreducible in $K[x]$, hence proving that $[\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{3}): \mathbb{Q}] = [\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{3}): \mathbb{Q}(i)] \times [\mathbb{Q}(i):\mathbb{Q}] = 2 \times 2 =  4$

Comment: Note that you can write $\sqrt[3]{-1}$ in terms of $i$ and $\sqrt{3}$ (and rational numbers) and vice versa, so $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[3]{-1})=\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{3})$. However the latter form is preferred, because there is no possible confusion with what a cubic root of a complex number means (since there is more than one way of doing it).